# Unique Metric Open Ball Proof: Show that if $x ∈ B(x0, r) \Rightarrow \exists s > 0 : B(x,s) ⊆ B(x_0, r)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-writing

> Let $(X, ρ)$ be a metric space, and let $x_0 \in X$. Show that if:
>   $$x \in B(x_0, r) \implies \exists s > 0 : B(x,s) \subseteq B(x_0, r)$$

The only similar problems I can find are “prove every point in a ball is a center of the ball,” which I believe tests the same concept but isn’t answered the same, by what I can tell anyway.

We don’t use a book, so this is presumably a problem the professor wrote, and in the print-off notes he makes, there isn’t anything other than the definition of an open ball and metric examples.

I think I know what it’s asking, after thinking about it for a while, and I can see why it’s true, but I don't know how to write a proof. Or maybe he doesn’t need a proof since it says “show,” not “prove,” but I figured I’d be safe with it.

Answer (score 1):

Try using s = r - d(x,x0).

Comment: can you explain please?

Comment: Prove that s is the answer.

Comment: yeah, but I don't know how. I don't know the method of proving these metric things. it's only the third class and there's no notes on how to do it. that's kinda the problem.

Comment: Pick a point p from B(x,s) and show p in B(x0,r).

Answer (score 1):

$x \in B(x_0,r)$ means that $d(x,x_0) < r$. So define our "wiggle room" by $r-d(x,x_0) > 0$.

Claim: $$B(x,s) \subseteq B(x_0, r)$$

Take $y \in B(x,s)$ then $d(x,y) < s$. Then by the triangle inequality:

$$d(x_0, y) \le d(x_0,x) + d(x,y) < d(x_0,x) + s = r$$

(the last equality by definition of $s$).

So by definition $y \in B(x_0,r)$ so the inclusion has been shown.